# Inherit from two classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, subclass

I am creating an universal iOS app, i.e. it will run on the iPhone and iPad. I now have a `UIViewController` that will be displayed on both, but differently. On the iPhone, it will contain a `UITableView`, on the iPad an `AQGridView`. The data will be the same. Both controllers will therefore share a lot of methods and instance variables.

Usually, I would create a `UIViewController` subclass with my methods and instance variables and then create two subclasses of this class where I put the stuff specific for the device.

The problem I'm facing now is that the iPhone version of my subclass should also inherit from an other class with some nice methods:

```
            UIViewController sublcass                   Some Other Class
                        |                                      |
            -------------------------------    -----------------
            |                             |    |
      iPad sublcass                 iPhone subclass
```

Adding the iPad version as a subclass of the `iPhone sublcass` is not possible as `Some Other Class` is designed to be used with a `UITableView`.

I'm pretty sure this is not possible in Objective-C but I wanted to ask before going ahead and creating a huge copy-&-paste mess. So: any suggestions on how to keep my code simple?

Comment: As I'm looking at a similar situation, I'm curious: why not use AQGridView on iPhone as well?

Comment: I'm using a `UITableView` there because I could only display about 2 `AQGridViewCell` s at a time.

Comment: Interesting. Can't you make the cells the same size as a UITVC?

Comment: You probably could. The problem is that with an `UITableView`, it is much easier to add sections and indices at the right side. If I used the `AQGridView` on iPhone, I would probably resize the cells so that four would fit the screen but would keep the aspect ratio similar to the ones on iPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, multiple inheritance is not possible in Objective C. However with clean and logical design it is not necessary and could be replaced with protocols. However if it is not the case for you (however, I have some doubts about that) I suggest you to check the [decorator design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Even if decorator pattern doesn't fit your needs I suggest you to use aggregation instead of inheritance (well, that is what decorator actually uses).

Comment: I thought it would not work because `Some Other Class` for instance does some `UITableView` set up in `-viewDidLoad`. When calling `[super viewDidLoad]` from an iPad subclass, stuff would go wrong. Anyway, I'm going to look into creating decorators now.

Comment: Mhm, I think I can put a lot of stuff into a separate controller class that will notify my iPad/iPhone subclasses of importent events via delegate. So, I'm going to accept your answer for now :)