# How to implement more than one controller in objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, model-view-controller, core-data, gridview

First of all I don't know If controller is the right word. What I want to achieve is this.

```
   @interface ClubViewController : CoreDataTableViewController :NRGridViewController
   {
```

I know that this is not possible in objective-C. But is there a way to work around this? 
Because I want to use CoreDateTableViewController and NRGridViewController.

Kind regards

Stef
**EDIT**

This is how my storyboard Hierarchy looks like.

```
-ViewController
  -TableView
      -View
      -TableViewCell
```

So I have a tableview Controller but above this tableview controller you find a small view with three buttons. When I push on button 1 I want to take the tableview away and draw a gridView with the NRGridview Controller. But when I push on button 2 and 3 I fill up my tableview using the CoreDataTableViewController.

I hope this explains more my problem.

Comment: I guess best is if you make a new view-controller, which can switch between a set of other view-controllers views.
You can save the view-controllers like the table-view-controller and the grid-view-controller in an Array and add/remove them from the view.

Comment: You should have a look at http://subjective-objective-c.blogspot.ch/2011/08/writing-high-quality-view-controller.html which explains in detail how UIViewController works and it's linked to a github project for the VC container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one way to do this is with a container view with a container view controller inside it. That container controller would have 2 child controllers which would be your CoreDateTableViewController and NRGridViewController. I've implemented something like this, and I can show you some code if you're interested.

After Edit: In a test app, I started with a single view template and a storyboard. I added two buttons to the top of the view and a container view to the bottom half of the view (this first controller is of class ViewController). I then dragged out a new view controller, and control dragged from the container view to the new controller and chose the "embed segue" (this will resize the view to be the same size as the container view). The class of this controller was changed to my subclass, ContainerController. I then created 2 more controllers for the 2 views that will be managed by the container controller (the views need to have their size set to "freeform" in IB so you can set the size to be the same as the container view). Here is the code in ContainerController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.cont1 = [[FirstController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:nil];
    self.cont2 = [[SecondController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondController" bundle:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:self.cont1];
    self.currentController = self.cont1;
    [self.view addSubview:self.cont1.view];
}

-(void)switchToFirst {
    if (self.currentController != self.cont1) {
        [self addChildViewController:self.cont1];
        [self moveToNewController:self.cont1];
    }
}

-(void)switchToSecond {
    if (self.currentController != self.cont2) {
        [self addChildViewController:self.cont2];
        [self moveToNewController:self.cont2];
    }
}

-(void)moveToNewController:(id) newController {
    [self.currentController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [self transitionFromViewController:self.currentController toViewController:newController duration:.6 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft animations:^{}
                            completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                [self.currentController removeFromParentViewController];
                                [newController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                                self.currentController = newController;
                            }];
}
```

The only code I have in ViewController are the IBActions for the 2 buttons that switch the views. Those methods just call methods in the container controller:

```
-(IBAction)chooseFirstController:(id)sender {
    [self.childViewControllers.lastObject switchToFirst];
}

-(IBAction)chooseSecondController:(id)sender {
    [self.childViewControllers.lastObject switchToSecond];
}
```

Comment: If you be so kind to show your code. But is this container view contoller compatible on other devices than IOS6 ?

Comment: @StefGeelen, I've updated my answer to show my code. The container view controller capability was added in iOS 5.

Comment: You can only control drag and embed segue to 1 view controller. What if you want to work with 3 viewcontrollers?

Comment: Do you maybe have a github project  were I can follow the full code ?

Comment: When you say 3 view controllers, what do you mean? Three container controllers, or three children of one container controller? The container controller can have as many children as you want. And, sorry, no, I don't have a github project. If you want, you can email me at rdelmar@comcast.net and I'll send you acopy of my project.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do in your code is creating a class that is a subclass of multiple other classes, which is not possible. If you really want to do this, check out this question: [Inherit from two classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168728/inherit-from-two-classes)

If you are trying to create multiple instances:
CoreDataTableViewController and NRGridViewController are just classes, which you will have to instantiate to get an actual object.
You can instantiate e.g. an NRGridViewController using

```
NRGridViewController *controller=[[NRGridViewController alloc] init];
```

I hope this answers your question, it is a bit difficult to understand your question.

Comment: I think that Stef wants to have two hierarchical controllers. As you said, it's really hard to understand his question.

Comment: I've updated my answer to cover this possibility, too. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of taking tableViewController, take normal TableView (drag and drop from the storyboard to the particular position on the view).
2. when the button 1 is pressed Make the Table View hidden in the buttons action method. and initialize the grid view / or set grid view hidden to NO. (all views have the property of hidden in ios)
3. when you press on the 2nd and 3rd button set the grid view hidden and set tableview hidden equal to NO. and fetch the coredata and store it in array or dictionary or you can reload the tableview. 
   (Initially, before pressing the button 2 & 3 , the table view has no values. so you can set a bool property that when you press the button 2  or 3 set the bool and use the bool to reload your tabe view )

if you did not get my explanation ping me back.